# Race condition when insert a row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, race-condition

I have 3 tables:

```
Counters: ID, ItemCatalogID, CurrentCounter

Item: ID, ItemCatalogID, Name, Description, OtherValue

ItemCatalog: ID, Name, Description
```

Counters table contains CurrentCounter of an item catalog, when I insert a row, I have to query DB, get the current counter of corresponding catalog, then update this value by one and use this value for OtherValue field.

For example:

```
update Counters set CurrentCounter = CurrentCounter + 1 where ItemCatalogID = 100;
select CurrentCounter into v from Counters where ItemCatalogID = 100;
insert into Item(ItemCatalogID, Name, Description, OtherValue) values (100, 'MyItem', 'Short Description', v);
```

But I wonder race condition can occur? How to improve my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your situation may likely provoque a race condition.

Do you need these counters at all? You can easily replace them with appropriate queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ItemCatalog WHERE ID=100;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item WHERE ID=100;
```

For successive field contents it is advisable to use `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns. But it seems that doesn't apply in your case.

But nevertheless, you can use the `COUNT(*)` approach from above:

```
insert into Item(ItemCatalogID, Name, Description, OtherValue) values (100, 'MyItem', 'Short Description', (select count(*) from Item where ID=100));
```

It might be that you'll have to alias one of the occurrences of your table:

```
insert into Item(ItemCatalogID, Name, Description, OtherValue) values (100, 'MyItem', 'Short Description', (select count(*) from Item AS I where ID=100))
```

This executes in one step and you won't have to worry about a race condition.

If you cannot change this due to whatever reasons, there is another solution: use table locking.

Prefix your statements with

```
LOCK TABLES Counters WRITE, Item WRITE
```

and suffix them with

```
UNLOCK TABLES
```

in order to have exclusive write access to them.

Comment: Suppose ``ItemCatalog`` with ID = 100 has 30 items. Now I want to insert the 31th item to ``Item`` table and ``OtherValue`` field of this item will be 31. How can I do it with your strategy?

Comment: I elaborated a bit more on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a newbie in PHP/MySQL world. I think I have to learn by hard.

Comment: @JohanGosh First lesson to learn there: these are two worlds. PHP and MySQL don't have more in common than an interface (well, strictly spoken, three interfaces...)